# Background task not calling the php page

Tags: php, android

Hey I have a php file that delete a table row from mysqli table by its id and I execute it using android AsyncTask but from some reason it doesn't do anything but when I execute the php code alone with a defined id parameter it works fine, can someone tell me what is the problem?

Here is the php file

```
  <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=******;dbname=****_ori;charset=utf8mb4', '******', '*****8');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$my_id = $_POST["pid"];

$stmt = $db->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1,$my_id);
$stmt->execute(); 
?>
```

and here is the android code:

```
  @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    id = strings[0];

    String insertUrl = "http://website/delete_id.php";




    try {

            URL url = new URL(insertUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("pid", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("80", "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
        Log.d("del",data);

        bufferedWriter.flush();

            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return "done";



    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "not";



}
```

}

Comment: When it doesn't do anything, can you log the HTTP request/response?

Comment: Why dont you log results and value of variables in a simple text file to know what is wrong cause is looks fine.